# The “coords” attribute of the <area shape="rect"> tag is not in the “left,top,right,bottom” format

Tags: javascript, html

This might be a duplicate question so I apologize for that. I'm mapping an image and using a plug-in [Image Map Resize](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer) and I get this error in my console. "The “coords” attribute of the  tag is not in the “left,top,right,bottom” format."

Here's my code:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Image Mapping</h1>
  <img name="parkMap" src="https://i.ibb.co/cbmgggd/AGRIECOMAP.gif" id="image" usemap="#image-map" border="0" width="100%">

  <map name="image-map">
        
                <area target="" shape="rect" coords=" 345, 204, 435, 283" href="kubo" alt="Kubo">
                <area target="" shape="rect" coords="439, 325, 500, 369" href="" alt="Bee">
                <area target="" shape="rect" coords="314, 356, 356, 384" href="" alt="Bridge">
           </map>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('map').imageMapResize();

    </script>
```

Comment: Your snippet seems to run OK - wonder if it's the leading space on the first area's coords that causes the issue - or all the spaces in all the coords

Comment: Thanks but it still display the error at the console. When I remove the plug-in, I can hover and  click through the coordinates that I plot(but it still display the error at the console). I also remove the spaces in the coords but still won't work.

Comment: Okay, I found my mistake. Due to the `width: 100%;` in the `img`, I think I get the coords wrong, the coords are there but not the place where I expected to, when I remove it,the image returned to its original size, then I get the coords again and even if I add the `width: 100%;`, the coords are still on the same place. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your coods have a blank space,you can delete this blank space.and `alt` is useless,you can use `title`

```html
  <map name="image-map">
    <area target="" shape="rect" coords="345, 204, 435, 283" href="kubo" title="Kubo">
    <area target="" shape="rect" coords="439, 325, 500, 369" href="" title="Bee">
    <area target="" shape="rect" coords="314, 356, 356, 384" href="" title="Bridge">
</map>
```